# Even months aren't showed on the graph

Tags: javascript

I have generated a Google graph on the page filled with some data. The backend part sends data for the months that there are values in the database.

The problem is that on the graph I see only the `odd` months. The `even` months haven't shown up at all.

What can be the problem?

Here is my drawChart function

```
function drawChart(chartData, startYear, endYear, countries_names, productTitles, selectedProducts) {
    var dataMapByCountry = {};

    productTitles.forEach(function (productTitle) {
        dataMapByCountry[productTitle] = {};
        countries_names.forEach(function (country) {
            dataMapByCountry[productTitle][country] = {};
            for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
                for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
                    dataMapByCountry[productTitle][country][`${year}/${month}`] = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    var years = Object.keys(chartData);
    years.forEach(function (year) {
        var yearData = chartData[year];
        yearData.forEach(function (item) {
            var productTitle = item[3];
            var dataValue = parseFloat(item[1]);
            var countryName = item[2];
            var yearMonth = `${year}/${item[0]}`; // Year and month
            dataMapByCountry[productTitle][countryName][yearMonth] = dataValue;
        });
    });

    let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year/Month'); // X-axis as string

    countries_names.forEach(function (country) {
        selectedProducts.forEach(function (productTitle) {
            data.addColumn('number', `${country} - ${productTitle}`);
        });
    });

    for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
        for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
            var yearMonth = `${year}/${month}`;
            var rowData = [yearMonth];
            countries_names.forEach(function (country) {
                productTitles.forEach(function (productTitle) {
                    rowData.push(dataMapByCountry[productTitle][country][yearMonth]);
                });
            });
            data.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }
    var options = {
        width: graphWidth,
        height: graphHeight,
        title: selectedProducts.join(', '),
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Value'
        }
    };
    
       ...

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Here is the output of what the server returns:

```
{
    "data": {
        "2022": [
            [
                "3",
                "2.39"
            ],
            [
                "6",
                "2.49"
            ],
            [
                "9",
                "2.75"
            ],
            [
                "12",
                "2.99"
            ]
        ],
        "2023": [
            [
                "3",
                "2.99"
            ],
            [
                "4",
                "2.99"
            ],
            [
                "5",
                "2.69"
            ],
            [
                "6",
                "2.69"
            ],
            [
                "7",
                "3.09"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "startYear": 2022,
    "endYear": 2023,
    "selectedProducts": [
        "Two percent milk price, 1 liter"
    ]
}
```

For the year 2023, there is data for months 4 and 6 but they aren't shown on the graph label on the X-axis as year/month but the values are shown on the graph itself.

And here is what the graph looks like
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think these are two separate issues. Missing axis labels is probably a config thing (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous). The missing data is clearly missing from 'what the server returns' so you should check that the backend is fetching and returning the correct output.

Comment: @Moob, thanks for the comment. The backend returns the correct output. Just there are months without any data and that's why I want to add 0's on the graph with the following line: `dataMapByCountry[productTitle][country][`${year}/${month}`] = 0;`. The thing is that for months 4, 5, and 6 for 2023, there is data but the labels 2023/4, 2023/5, and 2023/6 aren't visible. (second image shows that clearly)

Comment: As I say, the labels not showing could be a config thing. Google charts formats the labels based on their content, size and available space. See: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/205272248/chart-in-google-sheets-not-showing-all-axis-labels?hl=en and https://support.google.com/docs/thread/134842624/how-do-i-have-all-data-labels-show-in-the-x-axis?hl=en

Comment: The graphs are correctly showing the zero values. In what way would you expect the graphs to look different? How big would you expect a zero-size bar to be? Also, in the line graph you can clearly see the line along the 0 for these months.

Comment: @Moob, the values are correct. The labels below aren't because are missing `even` months which have values. For example: 2023/4, 2023/5, and 2023/6 are missing but on the Line graph you can clearly see them on the line. Going to check and try the links you've sent.

Comment: I'm getting confused. What I am saying is that the missing LABELS are nothing to do with the 'missing' data - its just that the chart is choosing to render every-other month. The labels 2023/4 and 2023/6 are not on the x axis but 2023/5 clearly is. Furthermore, all of your data is accounted for and rendered so I'm not sure what 'problem' you are trying to solve.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how Google Charts works. The problem in my head is that if I select 1/2020 - 12/2023 I expect to see all 36 months as LABELS and values only for months that there is data in the database. The months without data clearly that they would be with 0's. So, pure visualization that confuses me.